# Has anyone tried to integrate redactor.js with django-admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wysiwyg

Has anyone tried to integrate redactor.js with django-admin?

Redactor.js is a WYSIWYG text editor based o jquery. [Redactor.js website](http://redactorjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's a good fit for the admin interface. Check out https://github.com/hcarvalhoalves/django-redactor

Answer (score 0):

All projects that I find on github was not maintained for years and doesn't support last versions of django and python, so I wrote my own [django-imperavi-widget](https://github.com/dzaytsev91/django-imperavi-widget), which supports python 2/3 and django >= 1.8 version.